# How do I use the Reddit API to log a user in or register them in Spark and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, api, reddit, spark-java

My project team and I are currently working on a Single Web Application project using Java Spark in the back-end and Javascript, HTML and CSS (with Bootstrap) in the front-end. We use MySQL as our DBMS.

**We're trying to make a system to log a user on Reddit in to our site. We need Reddit to get a user's karma and not manage passwords and usernames ourselves.
We're using Reddit's OAuth API in order to ask for a token, and Reddit then redirects the user to our website again.**

We've made a button on our website to log the user in.
What we're trying to achieve is:

1. The user clicks the log-in button.
2. The user gets redirected to the Reddit login page and needs to give permission to us to use their Reddit account with a few permissions.
3. The user accepts the request and then gets redirected to our website. The Reddit API sends a GET request to `localhost/login` and appends the state and Reddit token  to the link (so the link becomes `localhost/login?state=STATECODE&code=REDDITTOKEN`).
4. In the back-end (Spark/Java), we catch that GET-request and extract the state and code. We then send the code to Reddit to get a JSON with the user's data (such as comment karma, link karma and username) using https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me.
5. The back-end then checks if the username is already in our `User` table. If it is, the user already registered, and the user gets redirected to the mainpage and gets logged in. (We do log-ins by assigning session IDs to users in out `User` table.)
   If, however, the `username`is not yet in our database, then the user gets redirected to the registration page/section of our website, and in some way, the username and karma-values are passed to this page.
6. The user then fills in the remaining details about their account (email, address, age, etc.) and then clicks on register. This then sends a POST-request to our server with all the details (username, comment karma, link karma, email, address, age, etc.) and puts that user in our Database. The user then gets logged into our website and gets redirected to our website.

**The problems we are facing right now is**
we don't know how we can pass the username, comment karma and link karma from our back-end to our front-end. We thought doing it with a cookie would do the trick, but this causes security-issues and just makes it more confusing for us.

Maybe there is a better way to handle this system. We would really appreciate suggestion for doing this in a better manner than this way. However, we have to deliver something working by Nov 10th.
**Is there a way to pass values from Spark/Java to a webpage when registering someone?**

I can share some bits of our code if wanted. Right now, our GitHub repository is private, however.

Your help is extremely appreciated. I might even buy you coffee.

Sincerely,
Jeroen Meijer.